# Are we Sankaras ( संकर according to Bhagavat Geeta Chapter 1).?

Tags: vedas, bhagavad-gita, dharma-shastras

In the first chapter of Sri mad Bhagavat Geeta, Arjuna said to Sri krishna that if this war happens then everyone in the world will become Sankara ( संकर)(Bhagavat Geeta 1.41-44) And later war occurred. Does it mean that we all are Sankara ( संकर).?

Comment: I would suggest you to read the BG with word-to-word translation along with commentary by any reputed acharya and not make up your own interpretations if you you are a novice in Sanskrit....eg: you can read online on Gita supersite.Some good commentaries could be that of HH Sripad Shankaracharya's; Sripad Ramanujacharya's; Sripad Madhavacharya's; Shri Madhusudana Saraswati's; Sant Jnaneshwar's Gudarth Dipika; Swami Mukundananda's etc...

Comment: @devibhakt the verse 1.43 refers to **varṇa-saṅkara** which in the context means unwanted progeny. "doṣhair etaiḥ kula-ghnānāṁ varṇa-saṅkara-kārakaiḥ

    utsādyante jāti-dharmāḥ kula-dharmāśh cha śhāśhvatāḥ” Meaning:-“Through the evil deeds of those who destroy the family tradition and thus give rise to unwanted progeny, a variety of social and family welfare activities are ruined"

Comment: 1.42 states “saṅkaro narakāyaiva kula-ghnānāṁ kulasya cha patanti pitaro hy eṣhāṁ lupta-piṇḍodaka-kriyā”
 Meaning - “An increase in unwanted children(saṅkaraḥ) results in hellish life both for the family and for those who destroy the family. Deprived of the sacrificial offerings, the ancestors of such corrupt families also fall”

Comment: BG 1.41 states “adharmābhibhavāt kṛiṣhṇa praduṣhyanti kula-striyaḥ
 strīṣhu duṣhṭāsu vārṣhṇeya jāyate varṇa-saṅkaraḥ” Meaning:- “With the preponderance of vice, O Krishna, the women of the family become immoral; and from the immorality of women, O descendent of Vrishni, unwanted progeny are born.”

Comment: @Rāmachandra Oh ! my comment is so irrelevant and incorrect here (what’s new hahaha:D) I will delete it real quick, thx for pointing this out  Edit, I removed it. My Sanskrit/Hindi skills are freakin awful. New Years resolution for 2023 is to get those up to speed. Very necessary 

Comment: In the above verses Arjuna is trying to convince Lord Krishna to stop the war and the following verses elucidate on what happens when a dynasty gets destroyed(stated by Arjuna)....

Comment: @Rāmachandra Makes sense, thx ! 

Answer (score 2):

Varṇa-saṅkara means mixing between different varnas. It essentially means the collapse of varṇāśrama-dharma.
It is true that most people in the modern day are a result of varṇa-saṅkara due to the mahābhārata war that happened about 5000 years ago. It also increased due to huna, yavana/mleccha invasions that happened in bhārata. In modern-day India, it is happening freely.
The solution is the re-establish the varṇāśrama-dharma in society on the basis of guṇa-karma as śrī-kṛṣṇa teaches in Bhagavad-gītā 4.13.

> catur-varnyam maya srstam guna-karma-vibhagasah tasya kartaram api mam
> viddhy akartaram avyayam

**TRANSLATION**

> *According to the three modes of material nature and the work ascribed to them, the four divisions of human society were created by Me. And, although I am the creator of this system, you should know that I am yet the non-doer, being unchangeable.*

Once the varṇas are re-establish then people marrying within the same varṇa will attract a same-varṇa soul in the mothers womb.

Answer (score 2):

There is no pure endogamous jati today. Name based varna and associated Gotra is a fantasy. No Hindu today really knows his varna.

For example, take a look at this shloka from Garuda Purana.

**Brahmana-hood is rare**

> The soul obtains human body after passing through series of births. O
> bird, in human body too, his birth as a Brahmana is rare event.

**Garuda Purana, Dharma Khanda, Chapter XIX**

Most of the people who think they are Brahmana because of a Brahmana name is not really of Brahmana Varna.

**Why is this so?**

Hindu scripture says that this is due to intermarriage between people with different Varnas. This is the reason why conduct should be used to determine Varna and not name.

**Yudhisthira’s view on Varnashram dharma**

> Yudhisthira said, " In human society, O mighty and highly intelligent
> serpent, **it is difficult to ascertain one's caste, because of
> promiscuous intercourse among the four orders. This is my opinion. Men
> belonging to all orders (promiscuously) begat offspring upon women of
> all the orders.** And of men, speech, sexual intercourse, birth and
> death are common. And to this the Rishis have borne testimony by using
> as the beginning of a sacrifice such expressions as -- of what caste
> server may be, we celebrate the sacrifice. **Therefore, those that are
> wise have asserted that character is the chief essential requisite
> .... Whatsoever now conforms to the rules of pure and virtuous
> conduct. Him have I ere now designated as Brahmana.**'

**(Mahabharata Aranya Parva Section CLXXIX)**

Puranas complain about intermarriages.

> Said the Fire God: Pusakara narrated to Parashrama (the tenets of
> faith and the laws of conduct to be observed by the different castes
> of people as laid down by the different Manus, which were disclosed to
> him by the god Varuna and a knowledge whereof imparts enjoyment of
> good things in this world and salvation in this next. Puskara said: "I
> shall presently discuss the articles of faith and the laws of conduct
> which should be adapted and observed by the four castes of people in
> their every day life, which were approved of, even by the god Vasudeva
> and which carry the sanction and authority of the different Manus.
> Cessation of all killing propensities, truthfulness, mercy, kindness
> toward all created beings, serving god, Brahmins and one's own parents
> and respectable relations, worship of one's ancestors, veneration
> towards the King, perusal of good and pious literature, forbearance,
> fortitude in suffering and theism are the virtues which should be
> cultivated by members of the four castes and by men in general.
>
> Since the investiture with the holy thread, a member of the twice-born
> caste is supposed to take a second spiritual birth and I shall
> describe the castes which children born of parents not members of the
> same caste, would respectively belong to. A child born of parents
> belonging to different castes would get the caste of its mother, but
> on the contrary a child born of a Sudra father by a Brahmin mother
> would be candala. Similarly a child born of a Kshatriya father by a
> Brahmin mother is called a Suta, while one born of a Vaisya father by
> a Brahmin mother would belong to a Devala caste. Similarly a child
> born of a Sudra father by a Kshatriya mother is known as a Pukkasa,
> while the one born of a Vaisya father by a Kshatriya mother is known
> as a Magadha. A son born of a Sudra father by a Vaisya mother is
> called a Ayogava and thousands of different castes have been known to
> have originated out of intermarriages between Vaisya girls and youths
> belonging to the above said hybrid castes.
> ............................ Thousands of hybrid castes have arisen
> out of intermarriages between Vaisya men and brides of other Pratiloma
> castes. A member of the Dashika community should earn the livelihood
> by means of women or by serving as a guard of the female
> apartments..... A man by renouncing this life (or the welfare of a
> Brahmin or for the forbearance of the common weal, becomes exempted
> from all subsequent re-births. **The hybrid races should be looked
> upon as the off-springs of the cravings of flesh of their respective
> parents.**

**Agni Purana Chapter 151**